# Check if there's a process running from Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

Currently, I am using:

```
private bool IsProcessRunning(string ProcessName)
{
    foreach(Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if(clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(ProcessName))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This bool returns `true` if process is running. This works fine in Console/WinForms application, but it's not working when I am trying to check if a process is running from a Windows Service. As we all know, Windows Services are running on different SID than other applications. So, does anyone know how can I check if an application is running on a different Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the ServiceController. I do not know if this might assist you somewhat?

Below is an example on how to use it

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);

switch (sc.Status)
{
  case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
    return "Running";
  case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
    return "Stopped";
  case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
    return "Paused";
  case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
    return "Stopping";
  case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
    return "Starting";
  default:
    return "Status Changing";
}
```

If you have to retrieve the status again, you will have to refresh the status before checking again

```
sc.Refresh()
```

Comment: I already have code for that, I don't need that. I need to to see if another process (any process) is running, not the service.